# Merge two datatables without duplicates in C#?

Tags: c#

I have two datatables 1. sourceDataTable and 2. TargetDataTable
I want to merge SourceDataTable into TargetDataTable without duplicates. I want it to happen like synchronize. All the rows should be updated and inserted accordingly in the targetdatatable.

I tried using

```
targetDataTable.Merge(sourceDataTable, true, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
```

Also,

```
sourceDataTable.AsEnumerable().Except(targetDataTable.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
```

How to successfully merge both datatable without duplicates?

Comment: The _preserveChanges_ parameter is meant to preserve the values in the destination table. If you want to update the rows with matching primary key in the destination table set it to _false_

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two data tables?  Like a unique item number or something?

Comment: There is no relationship. The schema of both of them are same. I just need to merge the data from source to target. @duerzd696